# how to split a vector to sub-vector based on the first part of the split

Tags: r

Suppose I have a vector of length `10`. Suppose further that I want to split this vector to two sub-vectors. This is fine. However, Suppose that the second sub-vector is based on the first sub-vector. For example,

let `Par <- c(0.6,0.5,0.7,0.4,0.6,0.9,0.2)`. Then, suppose that I would like to split it into two sub-vectors i.e.,

`par1 <- Par[1:5]` and I would like the second sub-vector to be the last two values of `Par`. So, I can use `par2 <- Par[5:7]`. That is fine. However, Suppose that I want to do it automatically. That is if `par1` is a vector of `n` values of `Par` then `par2` is a vector of the remaining values.  For example, if I have `length(parnew1) = 5` and `length(parnew2=3)` then, I would like to have like this:

`par1 <– Par[1:length(parnew1)]`

and

`par2 <- Par[?:length(parnew2)]` I put `?` here because I do not know how to start here. I would like to start from where the `par1` ends.

Any help, please?

Comment: par2 = Par[(length(parnew1)+1):(length(Par))]

Comment: @ManishSaraswat Thanks a lot. I really did not think about this.

Comment: @Sotos Thanks, this is also a great help.

Comment: or `par2 <- Par[-(1:length(par1))]` or `par2 <- tail(Par, -length(par1))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include operations inside the indexing in R. For example, if you set your length of `parnew1` you can create `parnew1` and `parnew2` like this. Note the difference between the variable defined as `length_parnew1` and the function call `length(Par)`.

```r
Par <- c(0.6,0.5,0.7,0.4,0.6,0.9,0.2)
length_parnew1 <- 5
parnew1 <- Par[1:length_parnew1]
parnew1
#> [1] 0.6 0.5 0.7 0.4 0.6
parnew2 <- Par[(length_parnew1 + 1):length(Par)]
parnew2
#> [1] 0.9 0.2
```

Created on 2018-03-01 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).